Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.setContent(javafx.scene.Node)" because "this.scrollPane" is null
I have a javafx program. The program is like this - the Ingredients Controller checkbox window is filled with names from the postgresql database. When you click on the checkbox, a card should be automatically created in the AddBiscuitController window, the card should be displayed in a Scrollpane with the name from the pressed checkbox, an input field and a button. I use the card for the card.the xml in which the label, field, and button are located. When I click on the checkbox, the following problem comes out Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.setContent(javafx.scene.Node)" because "this.scrollPane" is null. I've tried all the methods I know, but nothing helps. I will be very grateful for your help.
Here is my code block
public class IngredientsController {
    
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    private AddBiscuitController addBiscuitController;

    public void setAddBiscuitController(AddBiscuitController addBiscuitController) {
        this.addBiscuitController = addBiscuitController;
    }
    
    DbFunctions dbFunctions = new DbFunctions();

    @FXML
    void initialize() throws SQLException {
        List<AddIngredients> ingredients = dbFunctions.setIngredients();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 20, 20));
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        Label label = new Label("Выберите ингредиенты");
        label.setStyle(" -fx-text-fill: #696e81;  -fx-font-weight: 550;\n" +
                "-fx-font-family: 'Segoe UI Semibold'; -fx-font-size: 22; ");

        TextField textField = new TextField("Поиск");
        textField.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: #d3d4d6;  -fx-border-radius: 5; -fx-pref-height: 36px; -fx-font-size: 15px;" +
                "-fx-text-fill: #696e81");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label, textField);
        for (AddIngredients ingredient : ingredients) {
            CheckBox checkBoxIngredient = new CheckBox();
            checkBoxIngredient.setText(ingredient.getName());
            checkBoxIngredient.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
            checkBoxIngredient.setOnAction(event -> {
                String ingredientName = checkBoxIngredient.getText();
                AddBiscuitController controller = new AddBiscuitController();
                controller.addIngredientCard(ingredientName);
            });
            textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                String searchText = newValue.toLowerCase();
                for (Node node : vBox.getChildren()) {
                    if (node instanceof CheckBox) {
                        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) node;
                        String ingredientName = checkBox.getText().toLowerCase();
                        checkBox.setVisible(ingredientName.contains(searchText));
                    }
                }
            });

            vBox.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/com/example/demograduation/styles/checkbox.css").toExternalForm());
            checkBoxIngredient.getStyleClass().add("check-box");

            vBox.getChildren().add(checkBoxIngredient);
        }

public class AddBiscuitController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button btnAddBiscuit, btnChooseImage, btnChooseIngredient, btnSave;
    @FXML
    private TextField nameField;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    ObservableList<AddIngredients> ingredients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }


    public void addIngredientCard(String ingredientName) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/example/demograduation/screens/card.fxml"));
        try {
            AnchorPane card = loader.load();
            CardController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setIngredientName(ingredientName);
            VBox initialContent = new VBox();
            initialContent.getChildren().add(card);
            scrollPane.setContent(initialContent);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

I've tried to do this
private ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

but still nothing worked. I also checked all the ids of the elements and the controller of the fxml file. I have everything correctly specified, but it still gives me this problem. How can I solve it?

Debugging assistance requires a [mcve].

Anyway, ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(); is wrong, the loader will create nodes for you.  AddBiscuitController controller = new AddBiscuitController(); is wrong, the loader will create controllers for you.  There are likely other errors and many improvements that could be made.

It is is not a good idea to initialize a controlller in another controller. It is generally good practice to have only one controller assigned to one fxml file, and vice versa.
